How do I list the local branches that have been deleted from origin without deleting them?
I want to list all local branches that where pushed to the remote (origin) but are no longer present (on the remote) but my local branch still exists.
Searching for a solution gave me the following:

How to find local git branches that have been deleted from master - I don't think this answers my question, but if it does let me know.  This question was only about the branches merged into master.    My question is about any branch I have locally that is no longer on the origin (remote) git server.

Remove tracking branches no longer on remote - This is very close to my question, but this answer deletes the branches.  I'm interested in knowing what would be deleted if I ran git fetch --prune (from dillionmegida.com article)

List all local branches without a remote - not the same question



No local branches were ever on the remote (origin), so it is unclear what you are asking for. — git fetch --prune (which is so useful that I have it turned on by default) deletes remote-tracking branches whose tracked branch no longer exists on the remote; it has no effect on your local branches.

Thanks Matt.  I updated my question to be clearer.

I don't see how it's clearer. There is no automatic relationship between local branches and branches on origin (remote branches). You can pretend that there is such a relationship — in particular, it is common to pretend that the similarity of names indicates such a relationship. But there is no inherent rule that such a relationship exists. A local branch foo could be pushed to the remote branch origin/bar, and now where's your breakfast?

Thus I don't see what you're looking for, beyond the normal and obvious thing that all of us do: list the local branches, list the remote-tracking branches, look at the two lists, and think. What's so wrong with doing that?

This is a alias of shell functions I made to do this. It is made for zsh on my Mac, so you might need to change couple things up. Also I don't remember why I need to do two different methods to get the complete list, but it should be accurate as far as I've used it.
git remote prune origin --dry-run;echo "Gone branches:"; git branch -v | grep "\[gone\]" | awk '\''{print $1}'\
First is to see what git would prune from remote, and in the second we check what branches git says are gone from remote.

The command git remote prune origin --dry-run listed some branches on my remote that were not checked out locally.  I tried running git remote prune origin --dry-run | grep "would prune" | sed -e 's,.* origin/,,' | head -1 | xargs git branch -D to test it out on the first branch that was listed, and I got the error branch 'foo' not found.

To list the branches that still exit on the remote: you can use git ls-remote --heads origin. Adding a bit of formatting:
git ls-remote --heads origin | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed -e 's#refs/heads/##'
# will list names like:
main
develop
my/feature
...

git ls-remote --heads origin | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed -e 's#refs/heads/#origin/#'
# will list names like:
origin/main
origin/develop
origin/my/feature
...



If your intention is to see what remote branches you have locally which aren't present in the remote anymore, you can compare git branch -r with the list of branches still present on the remote,

If your intention is to see what local branches you have, which are set up to track a remote branch, and that remote branch does not exist on the remote anymore: you can use


# list all your branches _and_ their upstream if they have one:
git branch --format="%(refname:short) %(upstream:short)" |
  # keep only the branches that do have an upstream:
  grep origin/

and compare that list with the list of branches still present on the remote

I think you want 1., but I'm not 100% sure.

Aren't 1 and 2 the same thing? if not, I'm wanting #2.  I want to see what I have locally that was set up to track something on the remote and the remote branch no long exists.  I'm realizing that a useful alias would be one that lists all of the branches locally and remotely and uses the unix comm program to show me all of the branches (local and remote) and whether the branch exists local and remote, local only or remote only.  I'm working on that and will post an answer when I have it.

for context: 2. is a config setting, that gets stored in your .git/config file. You may have branch names mentioned here that don't exist on the remote anymore.
